# Is the binutils(arm-linux-as) able to specify imm offset with b,bl,blx...?

Tags: assembly, arm

I use arm-linux-as to assembly some arm instructions to get machine-code like this:

```
// arm.txt
.code 32
MOV R0, SP

// command line
E:\armgen>arm-linux-as -ahlm -k -mthumb-interwork -march=armv7-a c:\arm.txt
ARM GAS  c:\arm.txt                     page 1
   1                    .code 32
   2 0000 0D00A0E1      MOV R0, SP
```

For B,BL,BLX..., I can write this:

```
//arm.txt
.code 16
BLX .sub_xxx
.code 32
ADD  R0, PC
ADD  R0, PC
.sub_xxx: ADD  R0, PC

// command line
E:\armgen>arm-linux-as -ahlm -k -mthumb-interwork -march=armv7-a c:\arm.txt
ARM GAS  c:\arm.txt                     page 1
   1                    .code 16
   3 0000 00F004E8      BLX .sub_xxx
   5
   6                    .code 32
   8 0004 0F0080E0      ADD  R0, PC
  10 0008 0F0080E0      ADD  R0, PC
  12 000c 0F0080E0      .sub_xxx: ADD  R0, PC
```

However, this tool calculate offset of jump instruction automatically by tag, and, if my jump's offset is a large number, how can I do for this? Padding so many instructions between src and dst? I failed to test write offset like this:

```
.code 16
BLX #0xce0
```

Can anyone give me some directions...

Comment: Use `ldr ip, =.sub_xxx` (or `ldr ip,=0xce0`) to get the absolute address to `ip`, and then you can use `blx ip`.  The `lr` register would be more convenient as it is being destroyed anyway, but I am not sure if `blx` will work with it.

Comment: You can not specify an offset bigger than +/-32MB in ARM and +/-4MB in thumb.  It is a limitation of the CPU/ISA.

Comment: Thank you, I test it and found some problems: if I want to jump to 0x8404 at 0x8410 (0x8404-08410=0xfffffff4), I can use this text and get machine-code "FBFFFFEA":`.code 32
.sub_xxx : ADD R0,PC    
ADD R0,PC    
ADD R0,PC  
B .sub_xxx`

Comment: But I failed to get this machine-code with the text: `LDR ip, =0xfff4  
B ip`

Comment: The *branch* does not support a register.  Instead, you use `mov pc,ip`.